# Vue.js push to object which was passed through as a prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to push an object to a prop in Vue.js.

The prop originates from the main script, and is passed into the Car component as a prop. From the Car component I'm trying to do `this.propName.push({key:value});`

An exception then tells me that push is not a function.
If I `console.log()` the propName beforehand, I can see that observers are attached, and I do have a get and set propName method.

If I try to do the same push from the main script it works, sortof, if I do `mainScriptObject[0].push({key:value});` I get the same error. (here mainScriptVariable[0] is the value passed as the prop.

TLDR:How do I push to an object passed through as a prop in Vue.js?

Comment: Is `mainScriptObject[0]` an array? Try to output `typeof mainScriptObject[0]`  from your main script to confirm.

Comment: you can't push properties to an Object, `push` if a function of the Array type `Array.prototype.push`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to add to an `Object`.

First of all make sure you're using two-way binding on the prop using `.sync`.

```
<component prop-name.sync="mainObject"></component>
```

Then instead of `push`ing into the object, just create a new property in the object within your nested component.

```
this.propName.newKey = 'newValue';
```